# Adicionar parâmetro repetido no componenteTRESTRequest do Delphi

Tags: delphi, api

Boa tarde.

Estou desenvolvendo uma classe em Delphi, utilizando a API do Boleto Cloud. A classe já esta pronta e funcional, emitindo boletos e gerando remessa.

Essa classe é composta pelos componentes REST Delphi (THTTPBasicAuthenticator, TRESTResponse, TRESTClient, TRESTRequest), que serão gerados dinamicamente em tempo de execução.

O problema se refere ao parâmetro `boleto.instrucao`, que na API pode ser adicionado de forma repetida, gerando assim as linhas de instrução.

Porém verificando na minha classe, ela adicionando apenas o último colocado. Debugando o código, percebi que o delphi está omitindo parâmetros repetidos.

Existe um código PHP da documentação da API deles, que eles enviam essa requisição em formato array. Porém não sei como vou enviar em array, se o parâmetro que o componente TRequest pede é string.

Linha que adiciona o parâmetro:

```
RSTRequest.AddParameter('....',FPagador.EnderecoComplemento,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
.
.
.
. (mais de 10 parametros)

RSTRequest.AddParameter('boleto.instrucao',FInstrucao1.Text,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RSTRequest.AddParameter('boleto.instrucao',FInstrucao2.Text,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RSTRequest.AddParameter('boleto.instrucao',FInstrucao3.Text,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);

RSTRequest.Execute;

if RSTResponse.StatusCode <> 201 then
begin
    //erro
end
else
begin
    //sucesso
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o parâmetro aceita somente `string`, é só transformar o `JSON` em `string`.

Então, para incluir um `JSONArray` faça da seguinte maneira:

```
var
    JSArray : TJSONArray;
begin
    JSArray  := TJSONArray.Create;
    try
        JSArray.Add('"Atenção! NÃO RECEBER ESTE BOLETO."');
        JSArray.Add('"Este é apenas um teste utilizando a API Boleto Cloud"');
        JSArray.Add('"Mais info em http://www.boletocloud.com/app/dev/api"');

        RESTRequest.AddParameter('boleto.instrucao',JSArray.ToString,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    finally
        JSArray.Free;
    end;
```

Não esquecendo de declarar no `uses` `System.JSON` e `REST.Types`

Comment: Obrigado Daniel mais uma vez pela ajuda. Infelizmente não deu certo. Ao enviar, o boleto recebeu a instrução sem a quebra de linha e com erros nos caracteres acentuados. No PHP funciona de boa. Mesmo assim, obrigado!

Comment: @André Tente colocar assim: `RESTRequest.AddParameter('boleto.instrucao',JSArray.ToString,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST, [poDoNotEncode]);`